# SQL Server Case statement in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case

I tried to google for CaseStatement in WHERE clause. But i didn't find similar to my scenario.

Below is my SQL Statement with CASE Statement in WHERE clause. If **PartName = B**, then i should apply (**RecoveraleFlag = 1**) condition along with other conditions. Else This condition should not apply but all other conditions should remain.

```
FROM Rec.Communications A
          INNER JOIN REC.CommunicationTypes B ON A.CommunicationTypeKey = B.CommunicationTypeKey   
          INNER JOIN occ.Cases c ON a.CaseId = c.CaseId
          INNER JOIN occ.Claims cl on a.CaseId = cl.CaseId
          INNER JOIN ops.Concepts d ON c.ConceptKey = d.ConceptKey
          INNER JOIN OPS.Regions f ON d.MODSRegionKey = f.MODSRegionKey 
          INNER JOIN COM.RepriceRequestOccurrences e ON a.CommunicationId = e.CommunicationId
          INNER JOIN occ.Providers prv ON c.MODSProviderKey = prv.MODSProviderKey
  WHERE 
**(
    CASE WHEN f.PartName = 'B' and e.RecoverableFlag = 1 then 1
    ELSE 0
  END
  ) = 1**
  AND 
  b.CommunicationTypeCode = 'RREQ'
      AND f.Region = @Region
      AND a.CurrentFlag = 1
```

Here Case Statement in where clause is working fine if Partname = B. For Partname A, this will be 0=1 – **always false**. Because of this it is not returning any data.
Can anyone gives any alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a case statement, you would write this as:

```
CASE WHEN f.PartName = 'B' and e.RecoverableFlag = 1 then 1
     WHEN f.ParName = 'A' then 1
     ELSE 0   END   ) = 1
```

Is this the logic you want?

Many would think that the case statement is irrelevant here, and instead use:

```
WHERE ((f.PartName = 'B' and e.RecoverableFlag = 1) or (f.partName <> 'B')) . . .
```

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE 
    (
        f.PartName <> 'B' 
        OR e.RecoverableFlag = 1
    )
    AND b.CommunicationTypeCode = 'RREQ'
    AND f.Region = @Region
    AND a.CurrentFlag = 1
```

You might find reading on [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need a case statement at all.. The following should work...

```
   WHERE  f.PartName = 'B' 
     And e.RecoverableFlag = 1 
     AND b.CommunicationTypeCode = 'RREQ'       
     AND f.Region = @Region       
     AND a.CurrentFlag = 1
```

But if you want to use a case statement in a where clause, try to put it on the "other" side of the comparison operator from the column name so the query can process it without doing a table scan...
as an e.g.,

```
   Where f.Partname = 
       Case b.CommunicationTypeCode 
          When 'RREQ' Then 'B' 
          When 'NOTREQ' Then 'C'
          When 'OPT' Then 'D' 
          Else 'F' End
```